KR R3300 prime k URDF
Can anybody provide a URDF file for the KUKA KR R3300 prime k URDF robot?
I have found a git repository https://github.com/Daniella1/urdf_files_dataset/tree/main
the KR150 R3100 is included, but i need the R3300. Thanks in Advance
